# Inconsistent results using matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

What I would like to achieve is having a plot like

[image: resultulting image]

So, if the green line should have the line color of value 19, it should be the same color as between 19 and 20 on the right hand side. I also know exactly the range where I will have values (here from 17 to 25).

The approach below sometimes work, but strangely it does only work about each second time. When I execute it again, suddenly I get a completely blue line (rgb 0 0 255). Is there something wrong with my approach?

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

cmap = plt.get_cmap('cubehelix')

minval = 17
maxval = 25
bounds = np.arange(minval, maxval+1)

mynorm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin = minval, vmax = maxval)
sm = matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=mynorm, cmap=cmap)

color = sm.to_rgba(20)
ax.plot([0, 100], [0, 100], c=color, lw=2)

ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.90, 0.1, 0.03, 0.8])
cb = matplotlib.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax2, cmap=cmap, norm=mynorm, spacing='proportional', ticks=bounds, boundaries=bounds, format='%1i')

plt.show()
```

I'm using Python 3.5.0 with matplotlib 1.4.3.

Comment: The answer below answered my question, but just to answer your question, the matplotlib version I use is provided by my system and is not compiled by myself (arch linux).

Comment: Done. See https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5199

Comment: Great. It seems [it will will be fixed in 1.5.0](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5199). :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that the `c` parameter can sometimes produce non-intuitive results. However, simply using the `color` parameter tends to be much more consistent.

Does this code fix your issue?

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

cmap = plt.get_cmap('cubehelix')

minval = 17
maxval = 25
bounds = np.arange(minval, maxval+1)

mynorm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin = minval, vmax = maxval)
sm = matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=mynorm, cmap=cmap)

color = sm.to_rgba(20)
ax.plot([0, 100], [0, 100], color=color, lw=2) # Using 'color' instead of 'c'

ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.90, 0.1, 0.03, 0.8])
cb = matplotlib.colorbar.ColorbarBase(
    ax2, cmap=cmap, norm=mynorm, spacing='proportional', 
    ticks=bounds, boundaries=bounds, format='%1i')

plt.show()
```

This issue is referenced here, https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5197 it will be fixed in 1.5.0

Comment: OK that really helps. So is there a reasong for this behaviour (are c and color not the same?) or is this just a bug in the new matplotlib versions?

Comment: @user3445587: according to the documentation, they are the same (just as `lw` is an abbreviation of `linewidth`). I bet this is a bug. Please, report it.

Comment: @MeshachBlue: Thanks. I think it is better now (so that people do not get the wrong impression that using `color` is different from using `c`; except for that bug of course... they should always be equivalent).

Comment: @Peque Hmm... does that mean that my prior example is another bug?

Comment: @MeshachBlue: probably the same bug, yes.

Answer (score -2):

Your code looks fine. I ran it on Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (x86_64)|OS X 10.10.5 without getting your reported error.

Comment: This should be a comment instead of an answer. ;-)

Comment: "When I execute it again, suddenly I get a completely blue line (rgb 0 0 255)"